# Iteration over 2 lists in R

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply

I would like to do an iteration with 2 lists.

For a single case, I have one dataframe `df1` and one vector `v1`.

My reproducible example as below.

```
df1 <- data.frame(n1 = c(2,2,0),
                 n2 = c(2,1,1),
                 n3 = c(0,1,1),
                 n4 = c(0,1,1))

v1 <- c(1,2,3)
```

Now, I calculate an value (ses.value) for each row using this code

```
x <- (v1 - apply(df1, 1, mean))/apply(df1,1,sd)
```

Let's say we will have a list of multiple dataframes `l1` and a list of vectors `l2` (each list has the same number of elements) Now, I would like to run a loop for those lists by using the above code (the element of `l1` must go with the element of `l2` with the same position).

```
# 3 dataframes and 3 vectors
df1 <- data.frame(n1 = c(2,2,0), n2 = c(2,1,1), n3 = c(0,1,1), n4 = c(0,1,1))
df2 <- data.frame(n1 = c(1,6,0), n2 = c(2,1,8), n3 = c(0,2,1), n4 = c(0,7,1))
df3 <- data.frame(n1 = c(1,6,0), n2 = c(9,1,5), n3 = c(4,2,1), n4 = c(0,7,2))

v1 <- c(1,2,3)
v2 <- c(2,3,4)
v3 <- c(4,5,6)

# list
l1 <- list(df1,df2,df3)
l2 <- list(v1,v2,v3)
```

Since my lists are too big, using `for loop` might be not such a good idea, any suggestions using `lapply` or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `Map` to loop over the corresponding elements of each `list` and then do the calculation based on OP's code

```
Map(function(x, y) (y - apply(x, 1, mean))/apply(x,1,sd), l1, l2)
```

-output

```
[[1]]
[1] 0.0 1.5 4.5

[[2]]
[1]  1.3055824 -0.3396831  0.4057513

[[3]]
[1] 0.1237179 0.3396831 1.8516402
```

---

Also, if the datasets are really big, use `dapply` from `collapse`, which is more efficient

```
library(collapse)
 Map(function(x, y) (y - dapply(x, MARGIN = 1,
     FUN = fmean))/dapply(x, MARGIN = 1, FUN = fsd), l1, l2)
```

Comment: thank you so much, i would like to ask about the position of `l1`, and `l2`. When I changed the position of them, I got the error like `Error in apply(x, 1, mean) : dim(X) must have a positive length`. Can you explain abit about this?

Comment: @đứcanhlê the lambda function `x, y` corresponds to l1 and l2i.e. each element of l1 and l2, if you change the position, the x will be the vector and y will be the data.frame and `apply` doesn't work on a vector

Answer (score 2):

Since your lists apparently are large, you probably could benefit from `rowMeans2` and `rowSds` of the `matrixStats` package.

```
library(matrixStats)
Map(\(x, y) (y - rowMeans2(as.matrix(x))) / rowSds(as.matrix(x)), l1, l2)
# [[1]]
# [1] 0.0 1.5 4.5
# 
# [[2]]
# [1]  1.3055824 -0.3396831  0.4057513
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 0.1237179 0.3396831 1.8516402
```

---

*Data:*

```
l1 <- list(structure(list(n1 = c(2, 2, 0), n2 = c(2, 1, 1), n3 = c(0, 
1, 1), n4 = c(0, 1, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)), structure(list(n1 = c(1, 6, 0), n2 = c(2, 1, 8), n3 = c(0, 
2, 1), n4 = c(0, 7, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)), structure(list(n1 = c(1, 6, 0), n2 = c(9, 1, 5), n3 = c(4, 
2, 1), n4 = c(0, 7, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)))

l2 <- list(c(1, 2, 3), c(2, 3, 4), c(4, 5, 6))
```